# Is there a way to send a soap request using CHEF

Tags: soap, chef-infra

Is it possible to send soap request using CHEF ?

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically, but I'm sure you can find a Ruby gem for SOAP and can use that directly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html but it's build using the same logic as the rest of the chef resources, so you will not get an object back.

Think of it as a "fire and forget" type of resource.

You can also use `execute` resource with simple `curl`